# How to call the function of Ajax Success outside ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
let choiceContext = [];
let nameList = [];
const data = {
    resource_id: '9329755c-6406-4894-88b7-e7b04ccdfecc',
    limit: 10,
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.data.brisbane.qld.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    success:
        function sendIN(data){
            $.each(data.result.records, function(recordKey, recordValue) {
                //some code about addding data to choiceContext
                return choiceContext; //assume a result
            });
        }
});
const answer = sendIN();
```

Hi, in these codes above, there is a function which called `sendIN`, I just want to use the result of it in out of ajax...but it dose not work.

However, I have tried to use `document.Cookie`:

```
let choiceContext = [];
let nameList = [];
const data = {
    resource_id: '9329755c-6406-4894-88b7-e7b04ccdfecc',
    limit: 10,
};

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.data.brisbane.qld.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    success:
        function sendIN(data){
            $.each(data.result.records, function(recordKey, recordValue) {
                //some code about addding data to choiceContext
                document.Cookie = choiceContext;
            });
        }
});
const answer = document.Cookie;
```

It works, but it cannot store enough data, so I need to find another way to achieve this.

Really thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: "it cannot store enough data" - what does that mean? Also, why not use any other method, defined properly outside of that AJAX definition, and call that?

Comment: Because I found that if `choiceContext` has more than 300 elements, it will not be stored in a cookie.

Comment: And how is that related to AJAX? How would that work different if you could call `sendIN` from any other place?

Comment: You can just call another function from there passing the data and do what you want to do with that data.

Comment: This seems to be an X/Y problem

Answer (score -1):

for the first request you can do this:

```
let choiceContext = [];
let nameList = [];
const data = {
    resource_id: '9329755c-6406-4894-88b7-e7b04ccdfecc',
    limit: 10,
};

let succesFunctionSendIN = function sendIN(data){
            $.each(data.result.records, function(recordKey, recordValue) {
                //some code about addding data to choiceContext
                return choiceContext; //assume a result
            });
        };

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.data.brisbane.qld.gov.au/data/api/3/action/datastore_search',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    success: succesFunctionSendIN
        
});
const answer = succesFunctionSendIN({result[]});
```

now you have a function reference "**succesFunctionSendIN**"

second:
For store more data You can use HTML web storage.

HTML web storage provides two objects for storing data on the client:

1. window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date (max size 5Mb)
2. window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)Limited only by system memory

Before using web storage, check browser support for localStorage and sessionStorage:

your success function will be like this.

```
success: function(data) {
   if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
     localStorage.choiceContext = data.result.records;
   } else {
      // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
   }
 }
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn from your answer. How does this help to store more data? What makes you think that this data should be stored local storage?

Comment: Thank you, maybe I see it before, but I am not sure dose it allows updating?

Comment: In picture one, it does not work. I cannot call `sendIN` out of ajax

Comment: Hi Phoenix, have you seen my suggestion? for reference the success function outside ?